# Animate when another wrap panel is clicked

Tags: c#, xaml, animation, mvvm

I have a list view that is being populated with wrap panels through my binding. My code currently will animate the opacity on MouseEnter (opacity up to 1.0) and MouseLeave (opacity down to {Binding PanelOpacity}) just fine.  However, when I select a different wrap panel, I need the storyboard for MouseLeave to fire to reduce the opacity.

Snippet:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <WrapPanel x:Name="panelObject" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,7">
            <WrapPanel.InputBindings>
                <MouseBinding MouseAction="LeftClick"
                              Command="{Binding DataContext.GridClickCmd, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Grid}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding Server}"/>
            </WrapPanel.InputBindings>
            <WrapPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type WrapPanel}">
                    <Style.Resources>
                        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
                    </Style.Resources>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="{Binding PanelOpacity}" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1.0" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </WrapPanel.Style>
        <WrapPanel.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeIn">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="1.0" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="FadeOut">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="{Binding PanelOpacity}" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SourceUpdated">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard x:Name="ChangeSelection">
                        <DoubleAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                    To="{Binding PanelOpacity}" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </WrapPanel.Triggers>
        </WrapPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

I've tried using a few different Routed Events and none of them seem to fire when a different wrap panel is clicked.

Last thing I tried was this:

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="SourceUpdated">
    <BeginStoryboard>
        <Storyboard x:Name="ChangeSelection">
            <DoubleAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                        To="{Binding PanelOpacity}" Duration="0:0:0.2" />
        </Storyboard>
    </BeginStoryboard>
</EventTrigger>
```

Edit: I've got this in my C#.  It works fine currently, without animation:

```
 _viewModel.MainPanel.ToList().Find(x => x.Server == (string)parameter).PanelOpacity = 1.0;
 _viewModel.MainPanel.ToList().FindAll(x => x.Server != (string)parameter).ForEach(x => x.PanelOpacity = 0.5);
```

Second Edit: Added more tags to show location of code.
Final Edit: full ItemTemplate code added.

Comment: These events would generally go through the item panel instead of the children and LostFocus should suffice but events like SelectionChanged etc are still handled by the list and not the item's children.

Comment: I should add those parts...it's actually inside <ListView.ItemTemplate> <DataTemplate>.  Is that what you're refering to?  Still a bit of a newbie in the XAML-C# game.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there. I would probably make a custom Item [Style Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788747(v=vs.100).aspx) for it and build that functionality right into the VisualStateManager of the item. But then again, you could have some details I'm not thinking of as I fly-by comment on a Friday like a jerk lol.